# Only accept connections inside same LAN

Tags: sockets

How to make a server app only accept connections come from same LAN (machines in same gateway)?
For example, some distributed application has more than one process which run on different machine. These processes need to communicate with each other, so they need listen port but only for this LAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each gateway assigns addresses within its own subnet, so you would have your gateway check its internal IP address on the interface you are listening. Say this is `192.168.1.1` it would then only accept connections from IPs in the form `192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.255`. It shouldn't be too challenging to implement something to filter connections like this in whichever language your using.